# Finding linking path between two points in array php

Tags: php

I would like to find possible options from an array that connects two points.

Eg.

`$startPoint = 1;`

`$endPoint = 5;`

`$points = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 5] [4, 3], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 5], [1, 6]];`

function should return

`$possibleOptions = [[1, 5], [[1, 4], [4, 5]], [[1, 6], [6, 5]], [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]]`

Would be nice to add a possible option limit eg. if maximum of 3 combinations are allowed, then the function would return

`$possibleOptions = [[1, 5], [[1, 4], [4, 5], [[1, 6], [6, 5]]`

as `[[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]]` is a total of 4 combinations.

I have tried looping through the array and finding a direct match first. If no direct match is found i loop through points again and create a new array with all the points that have start point as first value. I then check if the new array has an element where the last value is the endpoint. However, i feel like it is repetitive code and could be optimized as I have to repeat the code for the the max amount of combinations. Just not sure how...

Here is an example of my code:

```
$results = [];

        $startPoint = 1;
        $endPoint = 3;

        $points = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [4, 3], [1, 4], [1, 3]];

        foreach ($points as $point) {
            if ($point[0] == $startPoint && $point[1] == $endPoint) {
                $results[] = $point;
            }
        }

        $newStartPoints = [];

        foreach ($points as $point) {
            if ($point[0] == $startPoint) {
                $newStartPoints[] = $point;
            }
        }

        foreach ($points as $point) {

            foreach ($newStartPoints as $startPoint) {
                if ($point[0] == $startPoint[1] && $point[1] == $endPoint) {
                    $results[] = [$startPoint, $point];
                }
            }
        }

        print_r($results);
```

Comment: what is the logic behind that ?

Comment: @pr1nc3 I have updated question to show example code.

Comment: What about [1,4],[4,5] ? It's still a valid chain based on the above logic

Comment: @pr1nc3 Yes you are correct

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution:

```
$startPoint = 1;
$endPoint = 5;
$max_combinations = 3;
$points = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [4, 3], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 5]];

$result = [];

for ($i = $startPoint; $i <= $endPoint; $i++) {
    $sub_result = [];

    if (in_array([$startPoint, $i], $points)) {
        $sub_result[] = [$startPoint, $i];

        for ($j = $i; $j <= $endPoint; $j++) {
            if (in_array([$j, $j + 1], $points) && $j + 1 <= $endPoint) {
                $sub_result[] = [$j, $j + 1];
            }
        }
    }

    if (count($sub_result) != 0 && (count($sub_result) <= $max_combinations || $max_combinations === -1)) {
        $result[] = $sub_result;
    }
}

sort($result);

print_r($result);
```

The first four variable declarations can be modified according to your needs.
Note that setting `$max_combinations` equal to `-1` it will mean that it will match *all* paths rather than having a limit.

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/AgvDg)

Comment: max number of combinations is 3 as per question thats why, try it with 4

Comment: Wow. Thanks for snippet. I do notice that this script is limited to the endpoint integer. However, in my application it is possible to have a combination where the linking number could be greater than 5. For example... if I add an point [1,6] then in the results there should be [[1,6], [6,5]]. Ill update the question. Thanks very much for your effort